# Xsl:call-Template XSLT

Tags: wso2, xslt-1.0

I'm Trying to call a custom template with call-template. but i always got error with that. can anyone helping me. what or which side i got miss.

My code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="LOCAL_XSLT_Validate" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <OperationValueRegex>
            <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="./Value/text()"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="MyTemplate">
                <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="$variable1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </OperationValueRegex>
        </xsl:template>
        
        <xsl:template name="MyTemplate">
            <xsl:param name="Value" />
            <xsl:when test="$Value != '' ">
                <Result1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fn:tokenize($Value/text(), ' ')[matches(., '\d+')]"/>
                </Result1>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Value><xsl:value-of select="$Value/text()"/></Value>
                <notification>Need input</notification>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```

THanks

Expected Result:

```
<OperationValueRegex>
    <Result1>1231423</Result1>
</OperationValueRegex>
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer and i change My Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="LOCAL_XSLT_Validate" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <OperationValueRegex>
                <xsl:call-template name="values">
                    <xsl:with-param name = "vals" select="//OperationValueRegex/Value" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </OperationValueRegex>
        </xsl:template>
        
        <xsl:template name="values">
            <xsl:param name = "vals" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="fn:tokenize($vals, ' ')[matches(., '\d+')] ">
                    <Result1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vals"/>
                    </Result1>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$vals = '' ">
                    <Result1>
                        <Value><xsl:value-of select="$vals"/></Value>
                        <notification>Need Input</notification>
                    </Result1>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <Value><xsl:value-of select="$vals"/></Value>
                    <notification>Wrong format</notification>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```